# Read int64 from node.js buffer with precision loss

Tags: javascript, node.js, int64

What would be the best way to read an Int64BE from a node.js buffer into a Number primitive, like readInt32BE reads an Int32?

I know that I'll lose precision with numbers +/- 9'007'199'254'740'992, but i won't get such high numbers in the protocol I want to implement.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to make the signed function. But you can do yourself by reading in 2 32 bit parts and then building a signed number from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript uses only 64 bit double precision floats. To read a long number you have to read two 32 bit integers and shift the high 32 bits to the left. Also note that there possibly is an information loss for long values not in the range of 9007199254740992 <= x <= -9007199254740992 since the internal representation uses 1 bit for the sign and 11 bits for the exponent.

Since the low part can be negative but must be treated as unsigned, a correction is added.

```
function readInt64BEasFloat(buffer, offset) {
  var low = readInt32BE(buffer, offset + 4);
  var n = readInt32BE(buffer, offset) * 4294967296.0 + low;
  if (low < 0) n += 4294967296;
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work! Tested it with two readInt16BE calls to read an readInt32BE. I just hope there won't be some overflow stuff in the negative part..

Comment: JavaScript only supports 64-bit floats, not 32-bit integers and 32-bit floats.  Also, why not use `readUInt32BE` to read the low part so that no correction is needed?

Comment: No, "Javascript uses 32 bit integers and 32 bit floats" is incorrect. All numbers are represented via 64bit double precision floating point which can safely represent all integers between -9,007,199,254,740,991 and 9,007,199,254,740,991. Please fix your answer.

Comment: Actually JavaScript supports 32-bit signed integers if you do bitwise operations. Thus  2 >> 32 = 2, not what you'd expect. A classic performance hack is to say "n|0" whenever you want n to be an int. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 4):

Don't try and code the conversion yourself, use a tested version like [`node-int64`](https://github.com/broofa/node-int64).

```
var Int64 = require('node-int64');
function readInt64BEasFloat(buffer, offset) {
  var int64 = new Int64(buffer, offset);
  return int64.toNumber(true);
}
```

Comment: Note that node-int64 is no longer maintained and, as the name implies, isn't intended for client-side JS.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest Node.js (12.0.0), you can use `buf.readBigInt64BE` :))